# Trying to figure out Ajax.BeginForm

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have a view in 2 sections.
The top section I input fields and submit to save them.
In the second section I have an autocomplete textbox. I select an item in autocomplete, and when I click submit I want to add that item to a datatable.
So for the first part when I click submit I save the details via a HttpPost method on the controller.
For the second part I intend to save it via an Ajax call for the controller and then bring back a partial view with the results. I have not coded the partial view yet, that is next.
Now I am new to Ajax.BeginForm and I am struggling with it.
I was hoping that the submit button inside the Ajax.BeginForm would only apply to that part of the form. 
But in fact it calls the HttpPost method for the whole form.
So how do I fix this?
My view looks like;

```
@using ITOF.HtmlHelpers
@model ITOF.Models.OngoingContractViewModel
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "EditOngoingContractDetails";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}
    @using (Html.BeginForm("EditOngoingContractDetails", "Contract", FormMethod.Post,
         new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
    {
        @Html.ValidationSummary(true)
        @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.Contract.ContractId)
        <h1>Edit Ongoing Contract Details</h1>
        <fieldset>
            <legend>@Model.Contract.Heading</legend>
            <p>Where you see <span class="error">*</span> you must enter data.</p>
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <td style="text-align: right">
                        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Contract.EndDate)
                    </td>                    
                    <td>
                        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Contract.EndDate)
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td style="text-align: right">
                        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Contract.Organogramme)    
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <input type="file" id="PDF" name="file" />
                        @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.Contract.Organogramme)
                    </td>
                </tr>
                @if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(Model.Contract.Organogramme))
                {
                    <tr>
                        <td></td>
                        <td>
                            The current organogramme is <span class="HighlightTextRed">@Model.GetOrganogrammeName()</span> 
                            for the contract <span class="HighlightTextRed">@Model.Contract.ContractName</span><br/>
                            <a href="@Model.Contract.Organogramme" target="_blank">Click here to see the last saved organogramme</a> 
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                }
                <tr>
                    <td style="text-align: right">
                        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Contract.AssistantRLOManagerId)
                    </td>                    
                    <td>
                        @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.Contract.AssistantRLOManagerId, Model.AssistantRloManagerSelectList, "--N/A--")
                    </td>                   
                </tr>
                @if (this.TempData["SuccessMessage"] != null)
                {
                    <tr>
                        <td colspan="2" class="success">@this.TempData["SuccessMessage"].ToString()</td>
                    </tr>
                }
                <tr>
                    <td colspan="2" style="padding-top: 20px; text-align: center;"><input type="submit" value="Save" /></td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </fieldset>


        <fieldset>
            <legend>Add an existing Site to this contract: </legend>
            @using (Ajax.BeginForm("AddExistingSite", new AjaxOptions { UpdateTargetId = "siteRows" }))
            {

                <input type="text" name="q" style="width: 800px" 
                       data-autocomplete="@Url.Action("SiteSearch", "DataService", new { contractId = @Model.Contract.ContractId })" />
                <input type="submit" value="Add site to contract" />
            }

            @if (Model.SiteList.Count > 0)
            {
                <table id="siteDataTable" class="display">
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th>Main Site?</th>
                            <th>Type</th>
                            <th>Address</th>
                            <th>Map</th>
                            <th>Telephone</th>
                            <th>Email</th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody id="siteRows">
                        @foreach (var item in Model.SiteList)
                        {
                            <tr id="@item.SiteContract.SiteContractId">
                                <td>@item.SiteContract.MainSiteFlag</td>
                                <td>@item.Site.SiteType</td>
                                <td>@item.Site.Address</td>
                                <td>@item.Site.MapUrl</td>
                                <td>@item.Site.Telephone</td>
                                <td>@item.Site.Email</td>
                            </tr>
                        }
                    </tbody>
                </table>
                <div class="add_delete_toolbar" />
            }
            @Html.ListLink("Back to List") 
        </fieldset>
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Oh no, you just cannot nest HTML forms. That's not supported. You will have to rethink your design. This really has absolutely nothing to do with ASP.NET MVC and things like `Html.BeginForm` or `Ajax.BeginForm`. The HTML specification simply tells you that the `<form>` tag cannot be nested and if you nest it you will get undefined behavior that could vary between browsers.

For example you could implement the autocomplete functionality using [jquery UI autocomplete plugin](http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/) and get rid of the `Ajax.BeginForm`.

Comment: What I want is to have 2 sections on my view that can update independently of each other. So I am thinking of partial updates and Ajax, but I am trying to work out how.

Comment: Great, but if you want to use HTML forms, then those forms cannot be nested. As I stated in my answer you will have to rethink your design.

Comment: In webforms you can do partial page updates, surely you can do this in MVC?

Comment: @arame3333, in classic WebForms you have a single `<form>` element for the entire page. Surely you could do the same in ASP.NET MVC. But the way you would do it will entirely depend on what you are trying to achieve more precisely.

Comment: I want to add a row of data to a grid without updating the whole form. The autocomplete is a way of getting the data that I want to add.

Comment: Alright, did you take a look at the `jquery UI autocomplete` component as I suggested you in my answer? You could of course reinvent the wheel and implement this functionality all by your hands if you will. You just should not use any `Ajax.BeginForm`.

Comment: The autocomplete works and was not the issue. The issue is that I wanted to click the submit button once I selected the item to update the grid without submitting the rest of the view at the same time. In other words I have 2 submit buttons that should only apply for 2 seperate parts of the view.

Comment: You will have to separate those forms if you want this to work.

Comment: OK I have move the brace for BeginForms to before the Ajax.BeginForm. But I then get an error when I click inside the autocomplete textbox. The error is in the Ajax.BeginForm command. In runtime this translates to <form action="/Contract/AddExistingSite" method="post" onclick="Sys.Mvc.AsyncForm.handleClick(this, new Sys.UI.DomEvent(event)); - and it does not recognise Sys.Mvc.AsyncForm.HandleClick

Comment: You seem to be using the legacy Microsoft Ajax* scripts. In ASP.NET MVC 3 those have been replaced with the unobtrusive jquery scripts. Make sure you have enabled them in your web.config so that you don't get this legacy `Sys.Mvc.*` stuff emitted by the helpers: `<add key="UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled" value="true" />`. Now Also make sure that you have included the proper scripts to your page (`jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.min.js`) for the Ajax.* helpers to work.

Comment: Yes I upgarded from MVC2 to MVC3. And whilst I was not importing those ajax libraries, I had not updated my web.config to <add key="UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled" value="true"/>. It was still set to false and that was the problem. Thank you!